# Filter out documents only if they contain a field with a value in lucene.net

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

In my index I have documents that have an expire date, they should not be displayed after a certain date. Not all documents have this field and if they do not have this field they don't have an expire date and can always be displayed.

So I'm trying to apply a rangefilter to filter out documents that have a "display_to" field with a value, but if the field does not exist in the document I want it to be returned in the query

This is the filtering code I've got so far but it's not doing what I want it to do.

```
BooleanFilter filter = new BooleanFilter();
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
filter.Add(new TermFilter(new Lucene.Net.Index.Term("modelId", modelId.ToString("N"))), Lucene.Net.Search.Occur.MUST);    
filter.Add(NumericRangeFilter.NewInt64Range("display_to", date.ToFileTimeUtc(), null , true, true), Occur.SHOULD);
```

Comment: "... it's not doing what I want it to do...": What exactly does it do? E.g. "throwing an exception", "returning all the records" "not returning records that don't have the field"? Can you make an "or" condition `display_to IS NULL OR  display_to <= date.ToFileTimeUtc()`

Comment: Well it's not returning documents where the field does not exists.